# Android Robotium - Have two tabhosts on screen

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I have two tabhosts on screen.
The tabs view is `android.R.id.tabs`.
I use:

```
ViewGroup tabs = (ViewGroup) solo.getView(android.R.id.tabs);
View viewYouWantToDoStuffWith = tabs.getChildAt(x);
solo.clickOnView(viewYouWantToDoStuffWith);
```

Just can only control one.
How can I do this with solo?